# Align Radio Button Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am quite new with front-end development and I am just trying to create a sample website. I used bootstrap for my template and I currently having trouble aligning radio buttons on it. Here's a sample of the code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="h5 mt-4 mb-4">Production Machine</p>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="desktop" name="prodMachine">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="desktop">Desktop Machine</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="laptop" name="prodMachine">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="laptop">Laptop Machine</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Transportation Availability-->
            <div class="col col-sm">
                <p class="h5 mt-4 mb-4">Transportation Availability</p>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="massTranspo" name="transpoAvail">
                    <label class="radio custom-control-label" for="massTranspo">Mass Transporation</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="privateVehicle" name="transpoAvail">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="privateVehicle">Private Vehicle</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can't seem to align the label. Here's a sc of this section:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxs76.png)

Did I made something wrong or I am just missing something?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your labels are aligned with bootstrap 4.5.0. Please run the code snippet.

**EDIT 1**: Add `<form class="border border-light p-5 m-0" action="#!">` to wrap the code. The misalignment is due to the `text-center` class added to the form. Remove it and the misalignment issue gone.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="border border-light p-5 m-0" action="#!">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="h5 mt-4 mb-4">Production Machine</p>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="desktop" name="prodMachine">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="desktop">Desktop Machine</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="laptop" name="prodMachine">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="laptop">Laptop Machine</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Transportation Availability-->
    <div class="col col-sm">
      <p class="h5 mt-4 mb-4">Transportation Availability</p>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="massTranspo" name="transpoAvail">
        <label class="radio custom-control-label" for="massTranspo">Mass Transporation</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-md-10">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="privateVehicle" name="transpoAvail">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="privateVehicle">Private Vehicle</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```